# Inline row editing - adding a select input option fixing re-scaling of input text box

Tags: jquery, css

I remade this code a little bit, I wonder how could I fix this annoying re-scaling when I click a field with value. Another thing is how to make a exception for the priority field to be a select input not a input I know that the code  `$(this).html('<input id="editbox" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');` is responsible for it. Probably a if would fix it or how could it be? I have been working on it quite a while and I am stuck. Thanks for any tips.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dpQe/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.edit').click(function () {
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

            $(this).addClass('ajax');
            $(this).html('<input id="editbox" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
            $('#editbox').focus();
        }
    );

    $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
            if (event.which == 13) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ticketmodifier.php",
                    data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rownum=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );

    $('#editbox').bind('blur', function () {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8dpQe/6/ Added something which finds the widest span. Also please note that the HTML is modified to include all the contents inside spans. Below is the core change.

```
    //find max width
    var maxWidth=0;
    var elementIndex=$(this).index();

    $(this).parents('table').find('tr:not(:has(th))').each(function(index,value){
        var element=$(value).find('td:eq('+elementIndex+')');
        maxWidth=(parseInt(element.width())>maxWidth)?element.width():maxWidth;
        debugger;
    });
    //end find max width
```

Comment: Nice I will try to fix it a bit more